# Как сверстать такую полосу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image]
как свертсать такую полосу, чтобы потом я так понимаю посредством логики(счетчика) она корректно продолжалась

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
.progress-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
}

.progress {
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 80%;">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```html
<progress max="100" value="25">
```